# C remove many elements in matrix?

Tags: c

Let's assume I have a matrix[4][10] that looks like this:

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

I want to enter a coordinate and remove everything to the right and below the coordinates.

For example, if coordinates are 3, 5 it will look like this:

```
**********
**********
****
****
```

If coordinates are 1, 1 it will look like this:

```
(blank)
```

I have tried to do this with loops, but I only succeed removing everything to the right of the coordinates, not everything below it too:

```
for(x; x <= 4; x++)
{
    for(y; y <= 10; y++)
    {
        matrix[x-1][y-1] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your 1,1 output doesn't match your 3,5 output.  Is 1,1 a special case?

Comment: My mistake, I just updated the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that after you complete your first iteration of the outer `for` loop, the value of y is not updated, so it will still be `11`.

```
void removeBottomRight( char matrix[4][], int x, int y )
{
    for( int xi = x; xi <= 4; ++xi )
    {
        for( int yi = y; yi <= 10; ++yi )
            matrix[xi-1][yi-1] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2952320 I told you the problem in the answer. You don't reset the iterator integer of the inner `for` loop, so it keeps the value that it had after the previous iteration of the outer loop. so the second time it goes into the loop `y=11`

Comment: @user2952320, you're visualizing your matrix with `x` representing rows and `y` representing columns.  As long as you're consistent then this is not a problem.  The code works, and the solution by @clcto works perfectly, but it's worth mentioning this labelling scheme may be opposite to what others expect. i.e. rows are typically the y axis, and columns are the x axis. I mention this in case you're sharing code or collaborating with others. Anyways, good luck with your project.

Comment: @DarrenStone yeah, I noticed that too, but it was the way he had it in his question, so I didn't want to change it.